# delayed for loop keeps returning same value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

My delayed for loop keeps returning "-1" no matter what i do.

```
for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, i * 1000)
}
```

(i changed my variable to 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way will be to call a function inside the `for` and let that function handle the `setTimeout`

```js
for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
  fnSetTimeout(i);
}     
            
function fnSetTimeout(i) {
 setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000 * i);
}
```

Comment: Even more simpler would be to declare `i` with  `let` instead of `var` ...